# How can I make this redstone staircase more compact?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I built a redstone staircase for my sky island on a server but its a bit too big. Can anyone help me decrease it's size?

World download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/343li2loe9me58f/Redstone%20stairs.rar?dl=0

The building was made with the diamond pillars. There are buttons at top and back to activate and de-activate.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: We're not here as a service on demand. Post a picture, and what you've tried. Downloading your world is a bit much.

Comment: Its a bit hard to see everything on the pics, but here anyway...

Comment: Are command blocks available? Or maybe any helpful plugin like craftbook?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: With plain redstone it would probably need at least (amount of spaces) * 3 pistons + at least 4 pistons to retract the top/bottom stairs that would get pushed away otherwise. So I guess you'd need  ~ 30 pistons to completely hide and show the staircase. You could probably save some space with more efficient redstone wiring.

Comment: Do you have a particular maximum size in mind, or do you just want it a little bit smaller?

Comment: I've found a design that's 11 wide, 11 deep, and 9 tall, not including the wall or floor.

Comment: Can you share the world save folder, not a random rar file?

Comment: I'll have time to look at this in a while, in cca. 10 hours.  I'll post my answer during the grace period of the bounty, if I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my design. It's 12x9x11, an improvement on your 14x8x16, and uses slime blocks to minimize the need for pistons.
[image]

[Schematic](http://www.minecraft-schematics.com/schematic/8127/)

If the schematic doesn't work, comment and I will look into other ways to show you. You do need to replace the torches with redstone torches, but be careful that the torch should be on and doesn't flicker. Also ensure that both sides aren't active at the same time, as things get really messy when that happens

Comment: I'm unable to play at the moment but will test this when i can. Can u add a world download?

Answer (score 1):

You can shrink it down quite a bit with command blocks, but you lose the cool piston-y look. But if you want to use it, here's a screenshot.
[image]

And here's a [world download](https://www.mediafire.com/?v61u818buk14c07).

Comment: OP has no command blocks available as stated in the comments.

Comment: @dly oops. Sorry I had missed that >.<